# How to merge builds for `iphoneos` and `iphonesimulator` as we used to do for frameworks using `lipo`

Tags: ios, metal, xcodebuild

As per title, is there way to have merged `iphonesimulator` with `iphoneos` build, so it can be distributed and used for both later?

I've tried `lipo` which complaints like the following:

```
fatal error: lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: *.metallib
```

also, I've tried `-destination generic/platform=iOS` which looks to be building for iPhone only, hence while running against simulator outputs the following:

```
Failed to created pipeline state, error Error Domain=CompilerError Code=1 "Target OS is incompatible: library was not compiled for the simulator" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Target OS is incompatible: library was not compiled for the simulator} -[MTLDebugRenderCommandEncoder setRenderPipelineState:]:1294: failed assertion `renderPipelineState must not be nil.'
```

Which brings me to my question - what is my options here?

Any suggestions is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Metal is its own compiled format, it is not like CPU code. There is no Simulator for metal so the question does not make sense. You should not use lipo on Metal compiled code.